# Update 'date' column using 'ValidateUpdateListItem' endpoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to update SharePoint document's metadata using `'/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitename/doclib/doc.txt')/ListItemAllFields/ValidateUpdateListItem'` endpoint within my (.netcore) webapi. This requires the date to be in specific format. The problem that I am facing is while I am able to successfully update the date column by transform date into `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt"`, if I try the other format  `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"` it throws an error:

> Invalid Data '02/17/2022 12:29:03' for the field  'Modified', Error:
> Enter a date and time like this: 2012-02-23 2:25 PM

The reason, I am trying the other format (`"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`) is because while it works for one SharePoint site collection (with the format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt"` ), it throws error on other site collection.:

> Invalid Data '2022-02-17 12:29:03' for the field  'Created', Error:
> Enter a date and time like this: 2/23/2012 2:25 PM

where the dates with the format `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"` seem to work, which is quite weird.
I have verified, both site collections have identical regional settings.
Is there any universal date format to convert the date into, that I am missing?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, in case it may help future visitors:
I somehow overlooked the `'locale'` setting in site's regional settings. In my case both sites are having different locale which is most likely the cause. So, I am wondering if there's a universal date format e.g. ISO 8601 string (that doesn't work btw) or something that I can use to convert dates into OR custom mapping (site's locale -> Date format) is the only solution for date column update

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the GitHub link below, the regional-setting-independent format in ValidateUpdateListItem is:

"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

[https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4917][1]